# StreamReader disable buffering

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, network-programming

I want to disable buffering in stream reader on TCP socket.
After streamreader.readline I use raw networkstream to readbytes.
Sometimes streamreader buffers data after new line \r\n and it causes my networkstream to hang forever because of missing bytes which was read already by stream writer.
How to disable buffering in it?

Comment: You can't. StreamReader requires buffering to read multi-byte characters.

Comment: Do `Read` instead of `ReadLine` maybe?